# Need help setting a cookie value with $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am running a script that sets a $_COOKIE['menu_item_id'] to the last insert id. I am doing this using jquery's $.post.

When the post request using $.post, I can't access that cookie in another part of my application. I can only access it in the same php page where post request was made.

I tested this out using sessions and that worked well, but I don't to use sessions for such a simple thing.

Why can't I access the cookie value through out my application ??

Below is my code.

```
index.php

    $.post("inserNewItem.php", {menu_cat_id : cat_id }

inserNewItem.php

//Preform the insert statment. Get the last_id and assign it to the cookie value "menu_item_id"
$last_id = $db->insert_id;
setcookie("menu_item_id", $last_id);



index.php

//Check if the menu item id has been set after the $.post ajax has been completed 

 if(isset($_COOKIE['menu_item_id'])){
  echo   $_COOKIE['menu_item_id'];
} else {
    echo "cookie is not set"; // I keep getting this 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at manual of [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). You have to pass as 4th parameter path as root `/`. Then cookie will be accessible on each part of your site. Example:

```
setcookie('YourCookie', $value, time()+3600, '/');
```

Remember to set also expire time. In example above it expires after one hour.

Comment: Ohh okay. Now I see why it wasn't working. Okay will do. Thank you very much marian0